# How to compare the results from each group with the overall across-group indicators in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My question is I can't figure out [the 10th question](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Neeps_medium_questions) as I tried to get the mean from a `GROUP BY` result. My wrong code is as follows

```
SELECT tc.staff,SUM(ev.duration)
FROM 
teaches tc
JOIN 
event ev
ON 
tc.event = ev.id
GROUP BY tc.staff
HAVING SUM(ev.duration)>AVG(SUM(ev.duration))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(rr.staff)
FROM (
    SELECT  tc.staff,
        SUM(ev.duration) as 'total'
    FROM 
            teaches tc,
            staff st,
            event ev
    WHERE   st.id = tc.staff
    AND tc.event = ev.id
    GROUP BY tc.staff
    HAVING total > (SELECT AVG(ss.total) as 'average'
            FROM  (SELECT tc.staff,
                            SUM(ev.duration) as 'total'
                    FROM 
                            teaches tc,
                            staff st,
                            event ev
                    WHERE   st.id = tc.staff
                    AND tc.event = ev.id
                    GROUP BY tc.staff) ss)) rr;
```

Answer (score -1):

change this

```
HAVING SUM(ev.duration)>AVG(SUM(ev.duration))
```

to this

```
HAVING SUM(ev.duration)>AVG(ev.duration)
```

Comment: Thx! @Pantamtuy But could you please explain a little bit to me? It seemed to me that it compares the `sum` with the `avg` within each group...

Comment: Isn't `SUM(anything)>AVG(anything)` True for multi-item, positive anything.  It seems the OP needs a second step.